# Kepler papers (2-body problem)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, history

Where can I find papers by Kepler? I am looking for his solution to the two-body problem.

Comment: This question is more about the history of physics than about physics itself, and is probably better suited to [HSM.SE].

Comment: It's also worth noting that Kepler's entire life pre-dates what is usually thought of as the first purely scientific journal, *Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society*.  So asking for "papers by Kepler" may be something of an anachronism.

Comment: You can find Kepler's books. But what two-body problem solution are you talking about? Newtonian mechanics was not invented either during Kepler's life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kepler did not have a formal solution to the two body problem.  The problem itself was not even defined until Newton's work on gravity developed a theoretical framework for it.  All that $F = \frac {GM_1M_2}{r^2}$ stuff that Newton developed did not exist for Kepler.

Kepler did discover that observations of the motions of the planets fitted ellipses.  This was an enormous contribution to science, but was not at all the same as solving the two body problem.  It paved the way for *discovering* the two body problem and explaining Kepler's experimental hypothesis using a theoretical model (by Newton).